# Zoom Image In C#

Tags: c#, .net

hi
I am writting a program.
there is two picturebox in it.
one is containing a full image and another one is small one and should contain part of full image mouse points in big picturebox.
I just want to implement a zoom feature with fixed ratio that show part of image under mouse cursor in big picturbox into the small picturebox.

I just want a Bitmap exactly size of my small picturebox witch has the zoomed Image.

PS: I don't want to use any additional libraries.

I don't want to resize my pictureboxes' sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new `Bitmap` of the desired size, call `Graphics.FromImage` to get a `Graphics` object that draws on it, then call the [`DrawImage` overload that takes two rectangles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040.aspx).

This overload takes a portion of the source image to draw and the bounds in the target image to scale it to.

Comment: graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; might be useful then, too.

Comment: PictureBox.SizeMode is going to be his next headache.

Comment: @Hans: Probably not; it sounds like his zoomed image will be the same size as the picturebox.